# $\ell_1$ and $\ell_\infty$ as complementary subspaces of Banach space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space, and let $X'\subset X$ - its subspace. Then the following propositions are true:

1. $X'$ is closed, $X/X' \cong \ell_1 \Rightarrow X'$ is complementary;
2. $X' \cong \ell_\infty \Rightarrow X'$ is complementary.

For the second one there is an option to try using Hahn-Banach theorem, as we do the same for proof of finite-dimensional subspaces.

More precisely, we can extend an identity operator $\ell_\infty \rightarrow \ell_\infty$ to the norm-one operator $X \rightarrow \ell_\infty$, but by the definition of complement subspace we should find closed subspace (such subspace is a kernel of extension, as I know, but why does it form a closed subspace?) and moreover show that $\ell_\infty$ is closed.

Comment: How $\ell^1$ is a complement of $X'$? You do not have a priori $\ell^1$ in $X$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov I meant that $X'$ complement should be $X/X'$, but $X/X'\cong \ell_1$, that is

Comment: But it does not prove that $X'$ is complemented! The factor space always exists, but it does not provide a complement.

Comment: @FedorPetrov well thanks, I was in doubts that it should be necessary the direct summand, and it is not in general, then at least this is not trivial :)

Comment: The first statement is true, due to the lifting property of $\ell_1$, but it does not hold for other $\ell_p$.

Comment: I give both as exercises when I teach the second semester of real analysis.

Comment: 'Complementary' means 'complemented', right?

Comment: @LSpice sure. 
I found a book with answers to my questions, after reading I will post the answer, if nobody else will do it.

Comment: btw, what is the question?

Comment: @PietroMajer how to prove it with not a big cost of words. I saw a proof for the first prop, but it is not trivial, well

Comment: the proof is indeed short, but needs some facts. I post a sketch below (although the question could be closed as it is not of research level)

Comment: I guess you mean "$X'$ is  CLOSED subspace of $X$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **(1)**, use **(0)**: for any Banach space $X$, $L(\ell_1,X)$ is isometrically isomorphic to the space $\ell_\infty(X)$ of bounded sequences in $X$. You may easily define a concrete isometry and its inverse. As a consequence: any surjective bounded linear operator $S:X\to\ell_1$ is a left inverse: use **(0)** to define a right inverse $R:\ell_1\to X.$ The proof of **(2)** is on the same lines: you need to prove that any injective bounded linear operator $R:\ell_\infty\to X$ is a right inverse.

(Also recall that: for bounded operators on Banach spaces, $S:X\to Y$ is a left inverse if and only if it is surjective and its kernel splits; $R:Y\to X$ is a right inverse if and only if it is injective and its range splits. Moreover, if $SR=I_X$, the splitting is $X=\operatorname{ker S}\oplus\operatorname{ran R}$ with projectors$[S,R]$ and $RS$).